# Dictionary of lock object in order to reduce latency in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, .net-4.5

When an *online* user send a message to a *offline* user , I keep those messages in a `ConcurrentDictionary` . each user is running/spinning in its own `Task`(thread).

```
 public static ConcurrentDictionary<int, List<MSG>> DIC_PROFILEID__MSGS  = new ConcurrentDictionary...
```

So the method look like :

```
/*1*/   public static void SaveLaterMessages(MSG msg)
/*2*/   {
/*3*/       var dic = Globals.DIC_PROFILEID__MSGS;
/*4*/   
/*5*/   
/*6*/       lock (saveLaterMssagesLocker)
/*7*/       {
/*8*/           List<MSG> existingLst;
/*9*/           if (!dic.TryGetValue(msg.To, out existingLst))
/*10*/           {                                                  
/*11*/               existingLst = new List<MSG>();
/*12*/               dic.TryAdd(msg.To, existingLst);
/*13*/           }
/*14*/           existingLst.Add(msg);
/*15*/       }
/*16*/   }
```

Please notice the `lock` at `#6`. I did this because if `2` threads are in `#10` , they will  both cause creation of a new `List` (which is bad).

But I'm bothered by the fact that I `lock` "too much".

In other words , If I send message to `offline-user-20` , there is **no** reason that one will not be able to send message to `offline-user-22`.

So I'm thinking about creating additional dictionary of locks :

```
Dictionary <int , object> DicLocks = new Dictionary <int , object>();
```

Where the `int` key is the `userID`

Later ,  initialize  each entry with `new Object()`

So now my method will look like :

```
public static void SaveLaterMessages(MSG msg)
{
    var dic = Globals.DIC_PROFILEID__MSGS;

    lock (Globals.DicLocks[msg.To]) //changed here !!!
    {
        List<MSG> existingLst;
        if (!dic.TryGetValue(msg.To, out existingLst))
        {                                                  
            existingLst = new List<MSG>();
            dic.TryAdd(msg.To, existingLst);
        }
        existingLst.Add(msg);
    }
}
```

Now , users can inset messages to a different offline-users without interfering.

**Question**

1) Am I right with this approach , or is there any better approach ?

2) I really hate to lock around the `ConcurrentDictionary`, it is 100% not right. should I make it a regular `dictionary` ?

Comment: ConcurrentDictionary is already thread safe. There is no need to use lock in order to read/write to it

Comment: @TienDinh Yes but that's not the problem here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ConcurrentDictonary [has tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378677(v=vs.110).aspx) to help you do the situation you are in, if you switch your retrieval/creation of your existing list to a single thread safe operation it makes the problem much simpler.

```
public static void SaveLaterMessages(MSG msg)
{
    var dic = Globals.DIC_PROFILEID__MSGS;

    List<MSG> existingLst = dic.GetOrAdd(msg.To, (key) => new List<MSG>());

    lock(((ICollection)existingLst).SyncRoot)
    {
        existingLst.Add(msg);
    }
}
```

This attempts to get the list from the dictionary and creates a new list if it did not exist, it then locks only on the non thread safe operation of adding to the list on the list object itself.

If possible a even better option is replace your `List<MSG>` with a thread safe collection like `ConcurrentQueue<MSG>` and you won't need to perform any locks at all (the ability to do this all depends on how messages are used once they are in the list). If you do need to use a List you don't need `Globals.DicLocks[msg.To]` to lock on, it is perfectly acceptable to lock on the list object that is returned from the collection.

One advantage you could get from a second lock object is if you are going to have lots of reads but very few writes you could use a `ReaderWriterLockSlim` to allow multiple concurrent readers but only one writer.

```
public static void SaveLaterMessages(MSG msg)
{
    var dic = Globals.DIC_PROFILEID__MSGS;

    List<MSG> existingLst = dic.GetOrAdd(msg.To, (key) => new List<MSG>());

    var lockingObj = GetLockingObject(existingLst);
    lockingObj.EnterWriteLock();
    try
    {
        existingLst.Add(msg);
    }
    finally
    {
        lockingObj.ExitWriteLock();
    }
}

private static ConcurrentDictionary<List<MSG>, ReaderWriterLockSlim> _msgLocks = new ConcurrentDictionary<List<MSG>, ReaderWriterLockSlim>();

public static ReaderWriterLockSlim GetLockingObject(List<MSG> msgList)
{
    _msgLocks.GetOrAdd(msgList, (key) => new ReaderWriterLockSlim());
}


//Elsewhere in multiple threads.

public MSG PeekNewestMessage(int myId)
{
    var dic = Globals.DIC_PROFILEID__MSGS;
    var list = dic[myId];
    var lockingObj = GetLockingObject(list);

    lockingObj.EnterReadLock();
    try
    {
        return list.FirstOrDefault();
    }
    finally
    {
        lockingObj.ExitReadLock();
    }
}
```

However I would still recommend the `ConcurrentQueue<MSG>` approach over this approach.

Comment: I didn't know about the GetOrAdd with a single line of lambda . this saves me 3 lines. and ,of course, your solution is much better. p.s. just of curiosity : would the _locks_dictionary_ approach would have work ? I mean  , would locking entry with #1 , would allow others to manipulate data on  List which is on slot #2 ?

Comment: *locks_dictionary* would have worked fine, it is just unnecessary and adds a unneeded additional dictionary lookup. Once you have your special "lock object" the two methods would behave identically. For your example gave in your comment: Yes others could work on slot 2 while slot 1 was locked.

Comment: @RoyiNamir There is no reason to use another dictionary here. Just lock on `existingList` or use  `lock(((ICollection)existingLst).SyncRoot)`

Comment: @RoyiNamir I updated my answer with a possible "3rd option" that uses a `ReaderWriterLockSlim` to allow multiple readers but lock on a single writer (Remember you need to `lock` on the list even if you are just doing a read operation because you can't have a writer and a reader at the same time).

Comment: @RoyiNamir as Sriram pointed out, it is better "etiquette" to lock on `SyncRoot` than on the object itself if it is available. I updated my answer to use it. You don't "have to do it" you are just "supposed to do it".

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I've changed it (like you suggested)  to `ConcurrentQueue` instead of `List`. but what about line 187 in http://i.imgur.com/WbS6jiy.png , what if i'm currently pushing to client but some other thread is running "SaveLaterMessages?" ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir should `PushAllMessages` remove items from the list as they are pushed? if No just do a `foreach(var msg in QMessages)` it does a moment in time snapshot of the collection when you started the `foreach` loop. If Yes switch your `ConcurrentQueue` out with a `BlockingCollection` and do a `foreach(var msg in QMessages.GetConsumingEnumerable())` that will dequeue the currently processing item from the collection as it processed in the `foreach`

Answer (score 0):

You could also wrap your "List()" code in a class with a singleton pattern that manages the lifetime of the list per user and adding / removing from it, then your concurrent dictionary and support code becomes lock free. Your "List()" could also be a concurrent queue and further reduce the work you need to do around locking for future adds etc.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx

For high volumes, you could also use a service bus type pattern to cross thread boundaries and create a queue for each user and push messages down it for consumption when the user comes back online.